# AutoFill Macro to Length

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to Fill a formula that I have in D1 and fill down D to the length of C. I am using the follwing macro and I am getting the following error - Compile Error: Expected end with

```
Sub Macro3()

Macro3 Macro



  Range("D1").Select
  ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*(-1)+RC[-1]"
  Range("D1").Select

  Dim LastRow As Long

  With Sheets("Sheet2")
  LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say that the error means you need to `end with` your `with` statement.

Comment: I left that off the post, will update but I still get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem was a simple one. I used the macro recorder to AutoFill a Formula Range and found that the Destination Range starts with the Formula Range, so

```
Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D" & LastRow)
```

Should be:

```
Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
```

Here is working code, both fixed and cleaned up a bit :)

```
Sub Macro3()

With Sheets("Sheet1")

  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  With Range("D1")
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*(-1)+RC[-1]"
    .AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D" & LastRow)
  End With

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it! Good note about recording the Macro; that's a good way to debug your own code in any case.